# How do i print keys without Values

Tags: python

code:

```
t = [('a', 0), ('b', ), ('c', 2)]
d = dict(t)
for k in d:
    print(k)
```

Output:

d = dict(t)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required

How do i get keys which has no value?

Comment: Can you use something else instead? Such as `('b', None)`?

Comment: The input which i am getting from other system sends some keys with no values. I dont have control on the input to change the value to None.

Comment: `t = [('a', 0), ('b', @), ('c', 2)]` you forgive to put `None` in the `@` place.

Comment: Do you really need dict there? I mean you can just use list comprehension to get all "keys".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about printing, it's about `dict()` requiring a list of tuples with two elements on creation. Either add a second element to all your 'empty' tuples, or create your dictionary as:

```
d = {i[0]: i[1] if len(i) > 1 else None for i in t}
```

or:

```
d = {i[0]: next(iter(i), None) for i in t}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Input

```
t = [('a', 0), ('b', ), ('c', 2)]
```

## Changing Input

The easiet way to do that is changing `t` to:

```
t = [('a', 0), ('b', None), ('c', 2)]
```

And your own code will work.

## Making Code

If you don't want to change your input `t` you can do this:

```
d = {x[0]: x[1] if len(x) > 1 else None for x in t}

# Or:
#d = {i[0]: next(iter(i), None) for i in t}

print(d)
```

Same as:

```
d = {}
for x in t:
    if len(x) > 1: d[x[0]] = x[1]
    else: d[x[0]] = None

print(d)
```